# Start Naming service with Eclipse for CORBA IDL in java

Tags: java, corba, idl

I am learning CORBA IDL and I am developing a Java Based Distributed System using Eclipse and ORB Studio. My questions is, Is there a way to start a naming service with Eclipse other than having to start it as so from command line?:

tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 1050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a External Tools following the steps:

1. Create an External Tool configuration in "External Tools..." then "New Configuration"
2. In the "main" tab
3. "Location":  C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
4. "Arguments": /c tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 1050
5. Go to "Common" tab check the "Allocate Console"
6. Click run button